# Powershell for retrieve local USB printer details and insert into WMI

Tags: powershell, printing, usb

I am trying to get USB printer model and serial from the Win32_PnPEntity, then insert these info into a custom WMI namespace, so that I can use the Hardware inventory function in SCCM to collect the info for reporting.

I noticed that the location storing these info varies from one manufacturer to another.

such as the FujiXerox stores in "USB Printing Support" while HP and Brother stores in "USB Composite Device"

what weird is after I somehow got the below code working on my computer, when I try it on other computers, it only returns the first character, such as:

Results on my computer (two USB printers connected)

| Model | Serial |
| --- | --- |
| HEWLETT-PACKARDHP_LASERJET_400_M401D | VNH3G0XXXX |
| FUJI_XEROXDOCUPRINT_P355_DB | YWG-50XXXX |

Results on other computers (eg. a HP printer with serial no. starting with V)

| Model | Serial |
| --- | --- |
| H | V |

I am a system administrator managing SCCM, occasionally using PowerShell to help on my tasks, I just completely stuck at the moment as I didn't find any hint that will trim the results.

Thanks

Andrew

```
$ModelInfo = @()
$SerialInfo = @()
$FullInfo = @{}
$Final=@()
$USBPrinterModels =  Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -Match "USBPRINT"}|select DeviceID
$USBPrinterSerials2 = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.Description -Match "USB 列印支援" -or $_.Description -Match "USB Printing Support"}|select DeviceID
$USBPrinterSerials = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.Description -Match "USB Composite Device"}|select DeviceID

Foreach ($USBPrinterModel in $USBPrinterModels)

{
    $ModelFull = $USBPrinterModel.DeviceID
    $Model = @{}
    $Model.model += ($ModelFull.Split("\"))[1]
    $ModelInfo += $Model
}

Foreach ($USBPrinterSerial in $USBPrinterSerials)
{
    $SerialFull = $USBPrinterSerial.DeviceID
    $Serial = @{}
    $Serial.serial += $SerialFull.Split("\")[2]
    If($Serial.serial -notmatch "&")
    {
    $SerialInfo += $Serial
    }
    
}
Foreach ($USBPrinterSerial2 in $USBPrinterSerials2)
{
    $SerialFull2 = $USBPrinterSerial2.DeviceID
    $Serial2 = @{}
    $Serial2.serial += $SerialFull2.Split("\")[2]
    If($Serial2.serial -notmatch "&")
    {
    $SerialInfo += $Serial2
    }
}
 
$MaxLength = [Math]::Max($ModelInfo.Length, $SerialInfo.Length)
for ($loop_index = 0; $loop_index -lt $MaxLength; $loop_index++)
{ 
 $Final += new-object psobject -Property @{
                   Model=$ModelInfo.model[$loop_index]
                   Serial=$SerialInfo.serial[$loop_index]
                         }
#    $Final+=$ModelInfo[$loop_index]
#    $Final+=$SerialInfo[$loop_index]
}

$Class = Get-WmiObject Win32_USBPrinterDetails -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If ($Class) {Remove-WmiObject -Class Win32_USBPrinterDetails}

$WMIClass = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass("root\cimv2", [String]::Empty, $null);
$WMIClass["__CLASS"] = "Win32_USBPrinterDetails";
$WMIClass.Qualifiers.Add("Static", $true)
$WMIClass.Properties.Add("Model", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
$WMIClass.Properties["Model"].Qualifiers.Add("read", $true)
$WMIClass.Properties.Add("Serial", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
$WMIClass.Properties["Serial"].Qualifiers.Add("key", $true)
$WMIClass.Properties["Serial"].Qualifiers.Add("read", $true)
$WMIClass.Put()

ForEach ($FInfo in $Final) {
    [void](Set-WmiInstance -Path \\.\root\cimv2:Win32_USBPrinterDetails -Arguments @{Model=$FInfo.model; Serial=$FInfo.serial})
}
```

Comment: Definitely would recommend to use the new `Get-Cim*` cmdlets. Anyways, can you show us how you're trying to run this against remote machines?

Comment: I ran it locally, but I found what I did wrong, replied below.
reading info about Get-Cim* now

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid,

When there is only ONE USB printer, the $ModelInfo and $SerialInfo become "String" type and caused the [loop_index] return the first character of the string instead of the first entry of the array.

I added a gettype check on the variables (surely not perfect).

```
$ModelInfo = @()
$SerialInfo = @()
$FullInfo = @{}
$Final=@()
$USBPrinterModels =  Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -Match "USBPRINT"}|select DeviceID
$USBPrinterSerials2 = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.Description -Match "USB 列印支援" -or $_.Description -Match "USB Printing Support"}|select DeviceID
$USBPrinterSerials = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.Description -Match "USB Composite Device"}|select DeviceID

Foreach ($USBPrinterModel in $USBPrinterModels)

{
    $ModelFull = $USBPrinterModel.DeviceID
    $Model = @{}
    $Model.model += ($ModelFull.Split("\"))[1]
    $ModelInfo += $Model
}

Foreach ($USBPrinterSerial in $USBPrinterSerials)
{
    $SerialFull = $USBPrinterSerial.DeviceID
    $Serial = @{}
    $Serial.serial += $SerialFull.Split("\")[2]
    If($Serial.serial -notmatch "&")
    {
    $SerialInfo += $Serial
    }
    
}
Foreach ($USBPrinterSerial2 in $USBPrinterSerials2)
{
    $SerialFull2 = $USBPrinterSerial2.DeviceID
    $Serial2 = @{}
    $Serial2.serial += $SerialFull2.Split("\")[2]
    If($Serial2.serial -notmatch "&")
    {
    $SerialInfo += $Serial2
    }
}
If ($ModelInfo.model.GetType().name -eq "String") {
 $Final += new-object psobject -Property @{
                   Model=$ModelInfo.model
                   Serial=$SerialInfo.serial
                   }
}
ElseIf ($ModelInfo.model.GetType().name -ne "String"){                   
$MaxLength = [Math]::Max($ModelInfo.Length, $SerialInfo.Length)
for ($loop_index = 0; $loop_index -lt $MaxLength; $loop_index++)
{ 
 $Final += new-object psobject -Property @{
                   Model=$ModelInfo.model[$loop_index]
                   Serial=$SerialInfo.serial[$loop_index]
                         }
    }
}
$Class = Get-WmiObject Win32_USBPrinterDetails -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If ($Class) {Remove-WmiObject -Class Win32_USBPrinterDetails}

$WMIClass = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass("root\cimv2", [String]::Empty, $null);
$WMIClass["__CLASS"] = "Win32_USBPrinterDetails";
$WMIClass.Qualifiers.Add("Static", $true)
$WMIClass.Properties.Add("Model", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
$WMIClass.Properties["Model"].Qualifiers.Add("read", $true)
$WMIClass.Properties.Add("Serial", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
$WMIClass.Properties["Serial"].Qualifiers.Add("key", $true)
$WMIClass.Properties["Serial"].Qualifiers.Add("read", $true)
$WMIClass.Put()

ForEach ($FInfo in $Final) {
    [void](Set-WmiInstance -Path \\.\root\cimv2:Win32_USBPrinterDetails -Arguments @{Model=$FInfo.model; Serial=$FInfo.serial})
}
$final|FT
```

Comment: You can also wrap it in `@()`, or cast an `[array]` type to it as well for a cleaner look